# Vue input loses focus after each provided or deleted letter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I want to use the quasar input to update my object from backend.
The object got the field called `name`

Here is the code

```js
<q-table
  :rows="state.rooms"
  :columns="state.roomsFields"
  hide-bottom
  :rows-per-page-options="[0]"
  row-key='name'
>
  <template v-slot:body-cell-name="{ row }">
    <q-td key='name' class="text-center items-center">
      <q-input v-model="row.name" dense square outlined />
    </q-td>
</q-table>
```

but the input loses its focus after every provided or deleted letter and I think its because the field is called `name` and `v-slot:body-cell-name` is buggy then because when I try exactly the same code with field called `number` and `v-slot:body-cell-number`, it works great.

How to fix this? Can I make any alias for the field of my backend object?

Comment: Try changing `row-key` from `name` to `id`, like `row-key="id"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Why!

To fix this issue, you have to know that how Vue works under the hood and what's the role of `key` in a looped content. You can read more about it [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key). If you read about `key`s, you would get to know that Vue keeps track of the components and if any `key` changes then Vue will "re-render" that node/component.

#### Why it happens on `name` field?

Now we know that if any component's key changes Vue will re-render it, and if you notice `row-key` prop on `q-table` component, it's `name`. You may ask that Vue knows about `key` then why `row-key` is messing up? For that you have to study Quasar documentation and you would come to know that it receives the prop as `row-key` but it uses it as `key` under the hood. So all this issue rotates around the `key`. Anyways, it happens on `name` field only and not any other field, because you have specified `name` as `row-key`, so whenever you try to change `name` field and as Vue is keeping track of the `name` field as `key` so it will re-render the specific field. And that's pretty much answers your other question as well:

> I think its because the field is called name and v-slot:body-cell-name is buggy then because when I try exactly the same code with field called number and v-slot:body-cell-number, it works great.

#### Some rules on `key`s

- `key`s must be unique! You can use `uuid` or `primary key`, if your data is coming from a Backend
- `key`s must not change! Don’t generate them while rendering.
- Don't use `index` in `v-for`

#### Let's fix the issue

Now we know the problem, should the solution be simple? YES! We need to update `row-key` to something stable, which is not changed. As you mentioned that the data is coming from a backend and I am assuming that it should have an `id` field, so we can use `id` as `row-key` as `row-key="id"`. But if you have any other field which is unique and doesn't change while updating the content in your table then you can use that as well.